# I would like to use a TimeSpan structure instead of an int- Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

I would like to use a `TimeSpan` structure instead of an `int`, rather than write what unit of time it's about.
How to convert?

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

example use:

```
var element = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//h1[@class='m-t30'][contains(.,'My Profile')]"), 15);
```

Comment: Selenium uses TimeSpan your extension method don't. So just change the parameter type simply from int to TimeSpan and hand it over to WebDriverWait unchanged.

Comment: @Ralf Can you help me?

      `  public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan timeoutInSeconds)
        {
            if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan);
                return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
            }
            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
`
Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change int to TimeSpan and to optional parameter as I see you want control flow based on provided timeout

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan? timespan = null)
{
    if (timespan is not null)
    {
      var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timespan.Value);
      return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
    }

    return driver.FindElement(by);
}
```

Usage:

No wait, only FindElement

```
var element = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//h1[@class='m-t30'][contains(.,'My Profile')]"));
```

With wait up to 30 seconds

```
var element = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//h1[@class='m-t30'][contains(.,'My Profile')]"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```